# Scrollable background with resizable Qt widgets on it

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to create a Qt window that

1. can be scrolled/panned by dragging its background (scrollbars should not be shown)
2. contains multiple sub-widgets at defined locations (which scroll with the background)
3. the sub-widgets can be resized by pulling their border

What I managed so far is to create a `QGraphicsView` with `setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag)` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#dragMode-prop. I then placed the sub-widgets on a `QGraphicsScene`, however, this didn't allow the sub-widgets to be resized by pulling their border.
I also tried to inherit my custom sub-widget class from `QDialog`, which allows `setSizeGripEnabled(true)`. However, this doesn't resize their content, and QDialog is probably not meant to be part of a QGraphicsView.

Any suggestions? It would also be ok if the sub-widgets behave like sub-windows that can also be dragged at their title bar, as long as they cannot be closed and they move when the background is dragged.

Comment: How do you place `QWidget` on `QGraphicsScene`? Frankly speaking I don't know any solution which would match your needs.

Comment: I use QGraphicsScene::addWidget to place widgets and QGraphicsView::setScene to set it as a scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look aside `QMdiArea` class (Qt documentation: [QMdiArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html)). By problem description it is what you need.
Of course, you can use `Graphics View Framework`, but, i think, it will be more difficult. If you choose such approach, very useful will be class `QGraphicsWidget` (Qt documentation: [QGraphicsWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicswidget.html)).

Comment: How can I pan/scroll the QMdiArea?

Comment: Ok, I overloaded the mouse events of QMdiArea to implement panning http://www.archivum.info/qt-interest@trolltech.com/2005-12/00075/Re-panning-a-QScrollArea-with-the-mouse.html